# Is there a general way to mark a JUnit test as pending?

Tags: java, junit, tdd, junit4

Before stepping into the TDD cycle, I like to sketch out the tests that need to be implemented - i.e. write empty test methods with speaking names.

Unfortunately I have not found a way to "paint them yellow" - mark them as pending for JUnit. I can make them either fail or pass. Now I am letting them fail by throwing an `Exception`, but I'd rather use an equivalent of `pending` from rspec.

Is there such an option in JUnit or an "adjacent" library?

Comment: I've personally used `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet implemented")` as an eclipse/intellij template.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`@Ignore`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html) to ignore the test,

or this library to introduce the `@PendingImplementation` annotation:

https://github.com/ttsui/pending

I don't think there are other ways to achieve this..

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with the pending lib from Tony Tsui. It's a pity that JUnit only offers a "skipped" semantics, but it's still the closest thing

Comment: +1 Even better with a comment in the @Ignore("not ready yet")

Comment: @MatthewFarwell I find that to be much less useful semantics `@PendingImplementation` is better because it will still try to execute your test, and let you know if the test actually passes, which reminds you to remove the annotation. Plus it's more descriptive and searchable.

Comment: Is there anything like this for Junit5?

Comment: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-disabling for junit5

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) or [@Ignore](http://api.dpml.net/junit/4.2/org/junit/Ignore.html), both are not quite what you are after but close. The 3rd party library [pending](https://github.com/ttsui/pending) also exists. I have not used it, but appears to do what you want.